# Angular Material: Remove item onDrop outside cdk component

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am currently using angular material CDK DragAnDrop for some list functionalities. 
What I'm trying to accomplish is:

- I drag an element from List A and drop it into List B.
  If I drag the element from List B and drop it outside List B (outside List A also) I would like to remove the element from List B.
- Is there some directive or api that I can use to validate that I'm dropping an element outside cdkDropList component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some directive or api that I can use to validate that I'm dropping an element outside cdkDropList component?

You may use the `isPointerOverContainer` property of [CdkDragDrop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop) event.

If the item is dropped outside a container, it will be set to false, otherwise true.